# how to change Default account for to No in sourceTree

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am working in SourceTree .i want to delete my Saved Password in Tools>option>Authentication.Default account for option is set to YES and it is not deleting .how can i change my default to No so i can delete it.
it is causing me problems to login when i push 
please help.

Comment: If its any conciliation you are not the only one - I would also like to know how to remove a saved password. Clicking delete does nothing!

Comment: Thanks for replying.let me know if you find out .

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to delete the file that correspond to the repo that you want to change/delte. This file is usually something like the following:

   `your_username@STAuth-bitbucket.org` or `your_email@STAuth-github.com`

   If you are using **Windows**, the file is under this folder:

   `C:\Users\<YOUR_USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree`

   If you are using a **Mac**, the file is under this folder:

   `~/Library/Application Support/SourceTree`
2. Then open the file `hostusernamemap` (with notepad or an IDE) under the same folder and delete the paragraph where you find your username (just search for it with the find tool)
3. Now you are ready to enter new usernames and passwords in Sourcetree when requested